# How to define constraints on multiple generics parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I am wondering why I cant get such simple thing like this on google. This code is not compilable. How can I do this?

```
public class TestStep<StartEvent, CompletedEvent> 
    where StartEvent : MyBase1, MyInterface1, new() &&
    where CompletedEvent : MyBase2, MyInterface2, new()
{
}
```

Please help.

Comment: This is not a duplicate! The referenced duplicate question asks about specifying multiply constraints for a single type. This question asks about specifying constraints for multiple types.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try without the "&&"

```
public class TestStep<StartEvent, CompletedEvent> 
    where StartEvent : MyBase1, MyInterface1, new()
    where CompletedEvent : MyBase2, MyInterface2, new()
{
}
```